# BotFramework:Change the language of the receipt card "TOTAL" label

Tags: botframework

Is there any way to change the language of the receipt card "Total" label. 
Instead of Total I want display in Japanese language "合計"
I set the locale to "ja" but it is not working.

Comment: Please post the code you used to set the locale.